# unable to locate directives

Tags: magento2, magento-1.7

I am new to magento, i am working on existing site.

Can you please help me. I found this {{unsecure_base_url}} syntax in Base link url.

Where shoul i find the value of unsecure_base_url value.

Comment: It's your site base URL, which you can find under system->congratulations and then find web tab click on it and then you will see base secure and UN secure URL fields.

Comment: You have to keep unsecure_base_url value blank if u have added the base url as your website link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 2 you will find value of `unsecure_base_url` at **Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Base Urls**

[image]

Base Url itself is `unsecure_base_url` .

You can check this value in `core_config_data` table with path `web/unsecure/base_url` .

Comment: thank you for your reply. i have a magento site and mapped to multiple domains with stores in production environment. what should i do if i want to run my local system? what changes i have to do?